# Insert a 1 after every +

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following data set in which I need to find and replace all occurrences. The variable can either contain one of the examples or multiple separated by a comma to end of line. Each is a 10 digit number with the `/TYPE=PLMN` at the end.

I'm currently using a rule that will take the 10 digit number which is a phone number so for example just using 10 number `2`s

```
([\+]?)([5]?)(\d{10}.*) +1$3

+2222222222/TYPE=PLMN
```

and add a 1 after the +

```
+12222222222/TYPE=PLMN
```

However when it encounters multiple instances it will only replace the first occurrence and not touch the remaining.

```
+2222222222/TYPE=PLMN, +2222222222/TYPE=PLMN, +2222222222/TYPE=PLMN, +2222222222/TYPE=PLMN
```

Any advice on how to take the

```
+2222222222/TYPE=PLMN, +2222222222/TYPE=PLMN, +2222222222/TYPE=PLMN, +2222222222/TYPE=PLMN
```

and turn all instances into

```
+12222222222/TYPE=PLMN, +12222222222/TYPE=PLMN, +12222222222/TYPE=PLMN,        +12222222222/TYPE=PLMN
```

Such as for any occurrence in the line of a `+` character with no `1` after it to insert a `1` till the end of line.

Comment: Use the [*global* flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/global) on your regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your regex has a greedy character: `.*` here:

```
([\+]?)([5]?)(\d{10}.*)
                    ^^
```

That will match everything following the first match and that will prevent any other matches since matches don't overlap. So even if you had the global flag, you wouldn't get the expected result with that regex. Just remove it and I believe it's safer if you use `/TYPE=PLMN` since you already specified it.

If you want to add a `1` after a `+` that is not followed by another `1`, then you'll have to use a negative lookahead.

```
/([\+]?)(?!1)([5]?)(\d{10})\/TYPE=PLMN/g, "+1$3"
        ^^^^^
```

But your regex can be improved a bit. You don't need to escape a `+` within a character class, and you can actually write it as: `\+?`. Same for the `([5]?)`, you can write it as `(5?)`:

```
/(\+?)(?!1)(5?)(\d{10})\/TYPE=PLMN/g, "+1$3"
```

That should do it I think.

Note: If you have a number like: `51234567890`, it will be converted to `+11234567890` (dropping the `5` there. That's what happens if you don't put back the `$2` backreference and I'm not sure if you did that voluntarily, so I just mentioned it here).

Answer (score 2):

Use global switch:

```
s='+2222222222/TYPE=PLMN, +2222222222/TYPE=PLMN, +2222222222/TYPE=PLMN'
r=s.replace(/\+/g, '+1');

//=> "+12222222222/TYPE=PLMN, +12222222222/TYPE=PLMN, +12222222222/TYPE=PLMN"
```